# How can gods defend from other offensive gods

Tags: magic, gods

In my worlds various gods embody elements and concepts. There are many ways they can reach godhod. Inheriting dead gods powers, mortals collective belief birthing gods etc. Gods power effect everything and anything that is related to their concept or elements. While their element and concept isn't just that they are much more. Sorry if I can't explain better at this point.

But here is the example. God of space. Doesn't just effect space. He also effect spaces of things. Like if humans can hold X amount of memories not their head. The God of space can increase that memory space capacity to infinite. Or God of ice can freeze other element, thoughts, tangible and intangible things etc. You get the point.

Gods to sustain themselves and grow more power they need mortal or any living beings to worship them. They sustain themselves from faith. While the faith is intangible concept. The gods can effect it. Such as God of fire burning faith of other gods that are coming out of worshipper. It's not that much of a problem.

What big problems is the others like corruption and poison. God of corruption corrupting faith of other gods. Turning them into corrupted gods. Or God of poison poisoning faith and as a result killing them.

God of fire can help by removing the impurities or God of time reverse them process or god of purification purifying supply faith. But they can help so much.

Some gods can protect themselves like God of earth hardening his faith lol. But beings like God of water can't protect themselves.

So I would like you guys to help me to balance out like those poison or corruption gods. I can't think of way how to deal with this problem

Comment: Hi @user86457, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and read through the first two bulleted pages in our [help]. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. It's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. So brainstorming Qs (like this one) don't fit well here. There's the possibility of a Q we can answer, but you would need to provide a list of all the gods of your world and their concept/elements, then identify just one "problem" caused by the gods in question so there's the possibility of one best answer. Please [edit] your Q with improvements.

Comment: They could have established a covenant, which prevents direct infighting

Answer (score 4):

### Mutually assured destruction.

Some enemies have powers that can hard counter other god's powers. This is certainly a risk, and a danger that any god has to face. The answer? Use your nukes.

If a rival god attempts to corrupt your worshipers, use your water powers to drown their temples and their cities in a sea of water. If they decide to go hot, you can go hot as well. You can program in an automatic genocide if they try to corrupt you.

### Get allies.

You can also work with other gods. You can make a pantheon that has magical protections against most threats. This makes you much more able to handle a rogue deity. Just get all your buddies to help you crush them.

### Hide your power.

If you worry that getting too close to a rival god will let them hurt you, segregate part of your power away in a hidden location. If they corrupt 10% of your power you can go get the other 90% and use it to nuke them.

Answer (score 3):

**Opposing forces**

For every action there is an equal and opposite action.

The god of poison's opposite is the god of healing. The god of corruption's opposite is the god of purity.

Gods can't directly oppose their opposite as their powers cancel out. If they start to influence other gods, it's in the interest of the opposite to stop it.

If everything is balanced, no god has real power over another which is why gods want mortals who can unbalance the scales.